# return empty string from preg_split

Tags: php, regex, string

Right now i'm trying to get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => 
    [2] => goodbye
)
```

Where index 1 is the empty string.

```
$toBeSplit= 'hello,,goodbye';

$textSplitted = preg_split('/[,]+/', $toBeSplit, -1);
```

`$textSplitted` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => goodbye
)
```

I'm using PHP 5.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$textSplitted = preg_split('/,/', $toBeSplit, -1);
```

Your split regex was grabbing all the commas, not just one.

Comment: @Mike thats what I get for being a regex cargo-cultist. LOL!

Comment: ;o)  On another note, Gumbo's pointer to explode in the answer below makes a good point: no need to use a regex for this.

Answer (score 5):

`[,]+` means one or more comma characters while as much as possible is matched. Use just `/,/` and it works:

```
$textSplitted = preg_split('/,/', $toBeSplit, -1);
```

But you don’t even need regular expression:

```
$textSplitted = explode(',', $toBeSplit);
```

Comment: +1 explode() should outperform preg_split(), plus it doesn't rely on PCRE

Comment: premature optimization. I'm already using preg_ in my code. A little cargo-cultism on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern splits the text using a sequence of commas as separator (its syntax also isn't perfect, as you're using a character class for no reason), so two (or two hundred) commas count just as one.

Anyway, since your just using a literal character as separator, use `explode()`:

```
$str = 'hello,,goodbye';

print_r(explode(',', $str));
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => 
    [2] => goodbye
)
```